# Tensorflow TFE_Py_FastPathExecute variable not found in pywrap_tensorflow.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was reading the source code for **LeakyRelu** in `gen_nn_ops.py` of `tensorflow.python.ops` package. The function in there calls `_pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute` with eight parameters.

However, `TFE_Py_FastPathExecute` member doesn't exist in `pywrap_tensorflow.py`. Where does it refer it from?

Answer (score 0):

In [pywrap_tfe.i](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tfe.i) lines 286 - 290 read:

```
// Since we wanted to have a function with a variable length of arguments, we
// used the native Python/C interface directly (which by default supports
// passing all arguments as a tuple).
%native(TFE_Py_FastPathExecute) TFE_Py_FastPathExecute_C;
```

This is likely referencing [pywrap_tfe_src.cc](https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6d014ecbd63fec208742b327b94c39afd4953fb8/tensorflow/python/eager/pywrap_tfe_src.cc) where we find TFE_Py_FastPathExecute_C in lines 1832 - 2132, starting with 
`PyObject* TFE_Py_FastPathExecute_C(PyObject*, PyObject* args)`.